# Pause loop to refresh API access token then resume

Tags: node.js, loops, token

I have an API that uses an access token, and a loop to update users in the system using that API:

```
while (socketerror == 0 && i < usersJson.length) {
for (let user of usersJson) {
functions.push(() =>
   userFunctions.updateUser(
   url,
   accessToken,
   user,
  )
 );
}}
```

I am looping through the users to update them, but the access token is expiring and I need to refresh it before I put it in the function.

I thought of putting the refresh call before each user:

```
if (new Date.now() < okapiExpiration) {
  accessToken = function refreshToken(accessToken);
}
```

but since they are running simultaneously, I fear that I will start asking for refreshed tokens for each one and get errors when I make the call.

Then I thought of using a while loop before I run through the users, but that will restart the loop of all the users each time.

Any idea how I can pause my loop, refresh the token, then continue the loop?

Comment: You can handle asynchronous operations using Promises and async/await syntax. This approach allows you to pause the execution of your loop to refresh the token and then resume the loop once the token has been refreshed.

Comment: My entire code is working with this syntax. I am making Axios calls with "return await" which already return promises, but how can that be implemented for the loop itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of the way described in the comments.

```
for (let user of usersJson) {
    if (Date.now() >= okapiExpiration) {
      accessToken = await refreshToken();
      okapiExpiration = Date.now() + 3600 * 1000;
    }

    await userFunctions.updateUser(
        url,
        accessToken,
        user,
      );
}
async function refreshToken() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));//just for test
  return 'new_access_token';
}
```

=========
Edit 1: To work it in a situation where multiple asynchronous operations are initiated at the same time, and they all may require a refreshed token if the current one is expired. The change ensures, that:

1. Only one token refresh operation is happening at a time.
2. All other operations wait for the token refresh to complete if it's in progress.

```
let accessToken = 'initial_access_token'; 
let defaultExpiration = Date.now() + 3600 * 1000;
let okapiExpiration = defaultExpiration;
let isRefreshingToken = false;
let refreshTokenPromise = null;

async function updateUserInformation(usersJson) {
  for (let user of usersJson) {
    if (Date.now() >= okapiExpiration && !isRefreshingToken) {
      isRefreshingToken = true;
      refreshTokenPromise = refreshToken();
      const newToken = await refreshTokenPromise;
      accessToken = newToken.token;
      okapiExpiration = newToken.expiration;
      isRefreshingToken = false;
    } else if (isRefreshingToken) {
      const newToken = await refreshTokenPromise;
      accessToken = newToken.token;
      okapiExpiration = newToken.expiration;
    }

    await userFunctions.updateUser(url, accessToken, user);
  }
}

async function refreshToken() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));//just for test
  return {
    token: 'new_access_token',
    expiration: Date.now() + 3600 * 1000
  };
}
```

Comment: That's the solution I ended up doing, BUT before I mark it as a correct answer: my fear is that in real time, since the users run simultaneously, it will cause several users to send update requests at the same time. As I am rewriting existing elements, can't it cause issues?

Comment: @NimrodYanai check the edited answer, I haven't chance to test it myself, but it should work.